# Alarm in javascript/Jquery to update database

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I'm trying to create an Alarm where I have to detect when a product starts and when ends.
It is possible to have a general alarm? I mean I won't be always on the same webpage... I mean I'd like to start the alarm on `localhost:8080/createProduct`, and if I'm in `localhost:8080/products` if the `alarm` fires get notified.
What I have to do is an Update to my db. 
On my createProduct I have the `startDate` and `endDate`, I've found a method on this [webpage](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/) where I found this method :

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
    var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
    var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );

    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}
```

So I can know the hours left and I can put it on this function from [javascriptKit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/alarm.shtml), instead of going to an URL I will have to update on my db.

Do you guys know any way to update the state of the product to the DB depends if it's ability or not?
I mean able is that `startDate` is equals than the current date (It will be on a form where you can choose the `startDate`), and if the `endDate` is the same than the current date the product would be disabled.

Hope I have explained correctly.

By the way, my `form` is like this :

```
<form method="POST" id="formdata" action="/createProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label >Name</label>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label >Start Date</label>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate" required="required" autocomplete="false"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="localTime" name="localTime" value="" hidden="hidden"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label >EndDate</label>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="endDate" id="endDate" required="required" autocomplete="false"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Create product" />
</form>
```